# Application of continuous property

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, proof-verification, continuity

Given f: [a, b] $\to$ R and is continuous. Also, f(x) > 0 $\forall x$ $\in$ [a, b]. I need to prove that there exists m > 0 such that f(x) $\geq m$ for every x $\in$ [a, b].

Since the function is continuous. f has global minimum m such that $\forall$x$\in$[a, b], we have f(x) $\geq$ m. Since f(x) > 0 in the interval, we have there exists m > 0 such that f(x) $\geq m$ for every x $\in$ [a, b]. Is my proof correct?

Comment: absolutely correct, you can even prove that exists m > o such that f(x) > m

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct.

Rephrasing a bit.

$f$ is continuos on [a,b], compact Interval; it attains its minimum.

There is a $x_m \in [a,b]$ s.t.

$f(x) \ge f(x_m) >0$, $x \in [a,b]$.

Choose $m=f(x_m)$.

Answer (score 2):

I think the key missing detail is not just that $f(x)\ge m$ for all $x\in[a,b]$, but that there actually exists $x_0\in[a,b]$ such that $f(x_0)=m$. That allows you to use the assumption that $f(x)>0$ always to conclude that $m>0$. Otherwise, one might be in a situation like the function $f(x)=1/x$ on $[1,\infty)$, which is positive everywhere on its domain but does not have a positive lower bound.